# System won't boot from USB (x86)

Tags: boot, usb, bios, bootable-media

I have a Lanner [FW-7551](https://www.lannerinc.com/products/network-appliances/x86-desktop-network-appliances/fw-7551)

I'm trying to install OPNSense, but it won't boot from my USB.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiClG.png

I was able to get into the bios and it recognize the USB.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt1k6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPzx5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdXZJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcYfM.png

However, if I continue to boot. It will only show this screen and stuck there with `#` character keep piling up. If I press anything on the keyboard, it will just add another `#` character.

It's always stuck at `F3`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipmWi.png

Pressing `F1` `F2` `F3` `F4` `F5` `F6` doesn't make any difference, only adding the `#` character

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ygYM.png

I've also tried different USB Drive, different bootable program (Memtest, FreeDOS), different software to write into the USB Drive(Rufus, ImageUSB). And it doesn't make any difference.

Any idea why?

Comment: Why do you have PXE enabled when your intention is to boot from a USB device?

Comment: You may disable all other boot options. It makes troubleshooting much easier if you only have to deal with one variable